# HTML show/hide div using CSS not working

Tags: html, css

to put it simply,

I have two divs

```
 <div class="menu-list">
    <div class="map-mobile" id="map"></div>
</div>
<div class="map-web" id="map"></div>
```

this is the corresponding CSS for the two divs:

```
.map-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.map-web {
    display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.map-mobile {
    display: block;
}
.map-web {
    display: none;
}
}
```

So essentially, when the screen size reaches 767px or less, the map for mobile displays and the web version hides. This works, whereas when the browser is of a normal size, the web map doesn't show. Any reasoning why this could be?

Thanks

Comment: Reproducing this code works just fine. Some other part of your code must be causing this. Also, note that `id`s must be unique. Different elements cannot have the same `id` attribute.

Comment: Whatever is causing it, is not related to the code you posted. Post a working example if you can, check console for errors